# Ionic v1 Marathi fonts are not rendering properly in html2Canvas

Tags: ionic-framework, html2canvas

On web Marathi fonts are rendering properly. But in Ionic v1 app Marathi fonts are not rendering properly. I am using html2canvas 1.0.0-alpha.12 version in with following method.

html2canvas(document.getElementById('imgCard'+index)).then(function(canvas) {

var imgTest = canvas.toDataURL();

});

Please help me, thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2173N.png)

Comment: Learn [how to use code block](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Not working with single word also.